# GraphQL Spring Boot suppress exception with HTTP Code

Tags: graphql

While fetching data with graphQL with invalid information
I am getting Internal Server Error in GraphQL which is expected.

In the logs, I can see the following Exception

Error executing query (ExceptionWhileDataFetching): Exception while fetching data : Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Now, I want to suppress this exception and wants to send the response with HTTP.NO_CONTENT_FOUND.

How it is possible in graphQL?
Any interceptor or Exception handling.
I am not able to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of GraphQL to return errors inside the response object? Here is some background: https://sachee.medium.com/200-ok-error-handling-in-graphql-7ec869aec9bc

Comment: I want to send No Content found Instead of ExceptionWhileDataFetching for this Exception only.
For any other exceptions, I don't want to handle